# Expand ENV vars from String

Tags: jenkins

How can I expand `${ENV}` variables in Jenkins Pipeline if they are in a string I do not control?

For example I have configured my Pipeline Job to load the Pipeline from a parameterized SCM:

[image: parameterized scm]

If I now access that branch via `scm.branches[0].name` inside the Pipeline I am currently getting `${REF}`, too.

(The `checkout scm` part of the pipeline works fine, thats not the problem.)

I have tried the `tm()` step, but that throws `org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Unrecognized macro 'REF' in '${REF}'`

---

I for example cannot use to update the build name:

```
currentBuild.displayName = "${scm.branches[0].name} (#$BUILD_NUMBER)"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `REF` is an Environment variable you can use String interpolation. Just put the variable into double quotes within the pipeline.

```
echo "${REF}"
```

**Update**

Not sure if there is better groovy way to do this. But following is an option you can use.

```
steps {
    script {
        script {
             echo "${scm.branches[0].name}"
             String branchName = "${scm.branches[0].name}"
             String envNameOnly = branchName.substring(2, branchName.length()-1)
             def env = System.getenv()[envNameOnly]
             echo "$env"
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not control the string.

Comment: @ciis0 I updated the answer with a possible option.